# Find a Blob in Azure Container

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have thousands & thousands of Blobs in a container, something like

- A/Temp/A001-1.log
- A/Temp/A001-2.log
- A/Temp/A001-3.log
- B/Tmp/B001-1.log
- B/Tmp/B001-2.log
- B/Tmp/B002-1.log

Now my problem is that I want to find Blob having A001 in its name. I understand that ListBlobsWithPrefix looks for Blob starting with some text which is not the case for me. ListBlobs would bring all the blobs to my code and then I would have to search for the one. Is there any way where I can just get the blobs I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

There's really no easy way to search a container for a specific blob (or set of blobs with a name pattern) aside from brute-force. And name prefixes, as you've guessed, won't help you either in this case.

What I typically advise folks to do is keep their searchable metadata somewhere else (maybe SQL DB, maybe MongoDB, doesn't really matter as long as it provides the search capability they need), with that data store containing a reference link to the exact blob. The blob name itself can also be stored in the metadata as one of the searchable properties.

Also: Once you get into the "thousands & thousands of blobs in a container," you'll find that pulling the blob names is going to take a while (which, again, I think you're seeing). Containers can certainly hold as many blobs as you want, but in that case, you really want to be accessing them directly, based on some other metadata, and not enumerating through the name list.

Comment: I understand that keeping searchable metadata separate makes sense but this is an existing application which is being taken to Cloud. I guess we really don't have much option over here, Right?

Comment: Well... there's always cache. If you're using web/worker, just create a cache role (or use co-located cache in your web or worker). Cache the names on a per-container (or per-prefix, or some other way) basis as you read them. Assuming all names would fit in cache, this could be a workaround for you.

Comment: Well that's something I don't know. I will have to research on it. In any case this wont help me as my App is a on-premise app and just my data is in Blobs. So its the on-premise app that's want to reach out to Blobs to get its data.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching, construct the blobname if its prefix is known and then try downloading the blob.If the blob doesnt found you will be getting 404 not found exception.

Answer (score 0):

As of today there's a preview feature available in few regions to allow for Blob Storage indexing:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-find-blobs?tabs=azure-portal

Hope they make it available soonn,

regards